# onclick in formtag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

How do I fix a reference to this button? I have a different form that has imgForm as Id so I cannot just use the tag name form. How can I, in javascript, make a reference when clicked on it will call a function?

```
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Start slideshow" id="slideShowBtn">
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't have (`I have a different form that has imgForm as Id`)

Comment: `document.getElementById("slideShowBtn")`? If not, your question is unclear.

Comment: It worked by doing PhistucK but not with "". Only ''.
document.getElementById('slideShowBtn');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be easily Googled but here you go:

```
var button = document.getElementById('slideShowBtn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('click');
}, false);
```